# Reading class names in a stylesheet

Tags: css, dom, stylesheet

I have an HTML document that uses multiple style tags.  One of those styles has the following content

```
<style id='pstyle'>
.p0010, .p0016, .p0022, .p0028, .p0032, 
.p0034, .p0038, .p0042, .p0044, .p0046, 
.p0048, .p0050, .p0052, .p0054, .p0056, 
{
 max-width:100%; 
 background-size:100%; 
 background-image: url('sprites.png');
}
</style>
```

`document.styleSheets` allows me to access the full set of stylesheets used by the document.  From there - once I have grabbed the right stylesheet - I can use the `cssRules` array attribute to access the `selectorText` attribute of each contained style.  However, I have been unable to figure out how to find the "right" style sheet.  Whilst I can give the stylesheet an `id` this does not turn up as an attribute of the document.styleSheets[n] object.

I do a great deal of DOM manipulation but it is mostly with the visual elements in the document.  I'd be much obliged to anyone who can tell me how I go about identifying the "right" stylesheet

---

A plain English version of the task

a. Find the style element - bearing in mind that there will be others - with the id `pstyle`
b. Read the class names defined therein and do whatever

Comment: When you say _to find the "right" style sheet_, what does that actually mean?

Comment: Sorry if the question was not clear.  I have put in a clarification

Comment: Well, as it is not valid to use the same id more than once, your `style` tags need unique id's. Still, don't understand what you mean with _find the style element_. I'm afraid you have to post a pseudo code sample to better explain what you are really after. Also `styleSheets` has these properties: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand if you want to get the stylesheet associated with the `<style>` element, or if you want to retrieve the element from the stylesheet.

So here you'll get both :

```js
// from the element
console.log(pstyle.sheet === document.styleSheets[2]);
// from the stylesheet
console.log(document.styleSheets[2].ownerNode === pstyle);
```

```html
<style id='pstyle'>
</style>
```

<sub>note that in the snippet it's `[2]` because stacksnippet does inject stylesheets</sub>

And now to get the cssRules and selectorText, you just have to read it from the selected styleSheet:

```js
var pstyle = document.getElementById('pstyle');

// from the element
console.log(pstyle.sheet.cssRules[0].selectorText);

// from the stylesheets
for(var sheet of document.styleSheets){
  if(sheet.ownerNode === pstyle){
    console.log(sheet.cssRules[0].selectorText);
    }
  }
```

```html
<style id='pstyle'>
.p0010, .p0016, .p0022, .p0028, .p0032, 
.p0034, .p0038, .p0042, .p0044, .p0046, 
.p0048, .p0050, .p0052, .p0054, .p0056 
{
 max-width:100%; 
 background-size:100%; 
 background-image: url('sprites.png');
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Perhaps I was not too clear so I have now put in a clarification.  Ultimately the `id` of the stylesheet does not interest me.  I just put it in hoping that I woudl be able to find that style element amongst a myriad of others that way.  What I really want to get at are the classnames defined in there.

Comment: @DroidOS I'm not sure I get it... You said in your question that you did know how to get these selectorText. All you seemed to miss was how to find out which styleSheet you are currently reading, my original answer shown exactly this. Nevertheless, I added a full snippet with two ways to get your selectorText. But now I'm wondering if your problem isn't simply that your CSS rule in the original snippet isn't valid (you've got an `,`at the end of the selector which shouldn't be there).

Comment: Thanks - the bit I was missing: I was not aware of the `sheet` property of the `style` element.